# How to create a background using CCRenderTexture?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to draw a simple background using CCRenderTexture.

I created a CCRenderTexture pointer(initialise with width, ht, pixel format)

cleare it with some color.

added to node,

added a label to node

==========================================================================================
When i am running it , i am seeing just black screen with hello world a label on it.

So where is that texture?

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    bool bRet = false;
    do 
    {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // super init first
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    CC_BREAK_IF(! CCLayer::init());

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // add your codes below...
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // 2. Add a label shows "Hello World".

    // Create a label and initialize with string "Hello World".
    CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString("Hello World", "Thonburi", 64);
    CC_BREAK_IF(! pLabel);

    // Get window size and place the label upper. 
    CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    pLabel->setPosition(ccp(size.width / 2, size.height - 20));

    // Add the label to HelloWorld layer as a child layer.
    this->addChild(pLabel, 1);

    CCRenderTexture *rt = CCRenderTexture::renderTextureWithWidthAndHeight(120, 120, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444);

    rt->clear(CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1());

    rt->setPosition(ccp(size.width/3, size.height/3));

    this->addChild(rt, 0);

    bRet = true;
} while (0);

return bRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This CCRenderTexture tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) is for Cocos2D iPhone but it may give you some ideas. The general principles are the same. For example you should try to create a separate sprite from that rendertexture, and add that sprite as child.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Scene::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();


    RenderTexture *rt = RenderTexture::create(120, 120, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444);
    rt->clear(CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1());
    rt->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/3, visibleSize.height/3));

    this->addChild(rt, 0);
    return true;
}
```

And this code generates this

[image]

I did not look at the date of the post.
I hope this will helps someone else.